# Open a workbook and then copy its 3rd tab whose name can differ?

Tags: excel, vba

I trying to do 2 things with my code:

1. Open a workbook. This workbook sometimes have 4 sheets, sometimes 5 or 6 sheets inside it.
2. Copy its 3rd tab into a target workbook which is also open. Code to be written in this target workbook.

Opening is fine because I am using below code:

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
path = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
Workbooks.Open(path)
```

But since the opened file's 3rd sheet name is not constant, I am unable to copy and paste it it using `ActiveSheet.Copy("Sheet3")`.

Any help how to copy-paste it into target excel?

Comment: Are the other sheets constant? If so, make note of them & then the other will be the 3rd sheet. You can cycle through the worksheet names using For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Debug.Print ws.Name
    Next ws

Comment: @ReturnVoid : No. The source book sometimes has 4 sheets within it, and sometimes 6. Names of 1st, 2nd sheets are constant but name of 3rd sheet which is to be copied varies. 4th , 5th sheets are sometimes present and sometimes not.

Comment: I would suggest adding a unique marker of some sort then in the 3rd sheet, like in $A$1 that identifies it somehow then. Then cycle through each sheet & check for that marker.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path)

wb.Worksheets(3).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'copy the 3rd sheet

wb.Worksheets(3).UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1") 'or copy content 

wb.Close False 'don't save
```

Comment: This simplistic code looks good but i was having issues because the source sheet was having some kind of protection. Can your code be tweaked a little so that it creates a new tab in target file and then copies column by column (the number of rows will vary). So all items in col A of source will get copied to Col A of target, then col B, till the last col (column count also varies).

Comment: "I was having issues" doesn't tell us much about what happens when you tried my code.  Did you get an error?  If Yes what was it?